# Unable to fetch tasks from all the task lists in SharePoint 2013 using CAML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

following is my Query:-

```
SPSiteDataQuery oQuery = new SPSiteDataQuery();

oQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"171\" />";
oQuery.Query = string.Concat("<Where>",
                               "<Eq>",
                                 "<FieldRef Name='Status' />",
                                 "<Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value>",
                               "</Eq>",  
                             "</Where>");
oQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +  /* Title is LastName column </Today>*/
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"StartDate\"/>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\"/>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"LinkTitle\"/>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"Body\"/>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"NewStarter\"/>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>";
oQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\" />";
```

I have 6 tasks lists in my SharePoint site. I can see tasks with status as 'Not Started' in the 6 task lists. However, in Visual Studio 2012, when I use CAML to query the tasks lists using ID as 171, I cannot see any tasks. Am I doing something wrong in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, pls check which site you are reffering to. Debug the application and check which items are fetched.

Use your site.url property in visual studio during debug/add watch.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using wrong ServerTemplate. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx) 107 is template id for Tasks. 171 is TasksWithTimelineAndHierarchy

Comment: I tried using 107, this does not return any results (0 results). However, using 171 I get the items of the workflow task list. But not other task lists

Comment: You right, now i noticed that 107 applies to old, 2010 tasks list template, and 171 is the new template from 2013 which should be used.

Comment: Another idea - maybe you can change oQuery.Webs to "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">", just to see if it return any results

Answer (score 0):

Also: SPSiteDataQuery does not support UserMulti in the AssignedTo field.

See this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2703054